# Code Logic to prevent clash between two reservations

Tags: php, oracle, algorithm

I am working on a meeting room reservation system in PHP 5.1 where I need to enforce a mechanism that no two users can reserve a room at the same time on the same day. The system stores time_in, time_out, from_date, to_date in a database. What algorithm should I use to prevent clash?

I initially thought to keep time_in and time_out fields `UNIQUE` in the database but in a scenario where user A books for `9 to 5 on 12-05-2014` i.e

`**User A**
time_in => 09:00
time_out => 05:00
reservation_date => 12/05/2014`

and user B comes and books for 12 to 3 the same day, i.e

`**User B**
time_in => 12:00
time_out => 03:00
reservation_date => 12/05/2014`

The system will accept the reservation since time_in time_out are different. So this algorithm will fail.

Also, people also have an option to reserve for days like I want to reserve room 1 for 10 days, each day from 9 to 5. So can anyone help me with the algorithm here?

Comment: You should store the time duration for example in terms of unix timestamp on which the room is not available. Then for any next reservation you can compute the unix timestamp of start and end and compare if those are available, That way you don't have to have exact string comparison (faulty) and you will know for sure whether that time is available or not

Comment: Is this a homework assignment where we can make some simplifying assumptions (i.e. a single-user system where we don't need to deal with multi-user complexities)?  Or is this for a real world system?

Comment: A real world system with multiple users

Comment: i don't think you need an algorithm for this just select the rows between the day  for that particualr room and if there is then don't allow insertion

Comment: What should be the query for it?

Comment: You would need two tables (for the sake of simplicity) parent table stores room number and Booked_status=Y/N. If booked_status=Y then a child schedule table would contain guest_id, room_no, time_in,time_out and can have multiple records with different time in and time out. Your logic can do a `LOCK IN SHARE MODE` to parent table while updating column `booked_status` which locks the room (temporarily) while being reserved but lets others view it. Once the lock is released, you check the time slots in child table and based on that present available time slots for reservation for the room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, I assume that a reservation such as

`room: 1`
   `time_in: 9:00`, `time_out: 13:00`,
   `from_date: 11/01/2014`, `to_date: 11/03/2014`

means that on the three days Nov 1, 2, and 3, the room is reserved from 9am to 1pm on each of those days. That is, it does not mean the reservation starts at 9am on Nov 1 and runs continuously until 1pm on Nov 3.

With these assumptions, the fundamental problem that needs to be solved is to determine if two reservations would overlap or not. For compactness, I will represent a reservation here as a tuple:

`[room, time_in, time_out, from_date, to_date]`

Two reservations overlap if the rooms are the same and *both* the time ranges and the date ranges overlap. That is, given reservations `[r,a,b,c,d]` and `[R,A,B,C,D]`, they overlap if `r = R`,  `a..b` overlaps `A..B`, and `c..d` overlaps `C..D`. Date and time overlap occurs if and only if

```
r = R   and   b >= A and a <= B    and   c >= D and d <= C
```

Using the expression above you can write a query that counts all existing tuples in the database that would conflict with a proposed new reservation, and insert the proposed reservation if the count is zero. (Lower case letters would be parameters to your query representing the proposed reservation, the capital letters would be the columns names in the database. I'll leave it to you to figure out the SQL to do the count and conditional insert.)

Note that it may not be immediately obvious that the overlap comparisons are correct. You can convince yourself that they are by looking at all the ways two time (or date) ranges could occur. Shown below are the possible relationships for the time ranges. The parens and angle brackets are intended to help visualize the two endpoints of each range.

```
(a   b)   <A   B>   condition b >= A fails, no overlap
(a   <A   b)   B>   both conditions met, overlap
(a   <A   B>   b)   both conditions met, overlap
<A   (a   b)   B>   both conditions met, overlap
<A   (a   D>   b)   both conditions met, overlap
<A   B>   (a   b)   condition a <= B fails, no overlap
```

Comment: you're an ultimate genius :) One thing more, if user A reserves for 9-5 and User B reserves after user A from 12-3 the same date, would this condition prevent overlap?

Comment: A single date is just a special case of a date range, where the `to_date` and `from_date` are the same. For example, given the single date 11/1, the date range representation is (11/1,11/1). So if you have two dates represented as ranges, `(c,d)` and `(C,D)`, and you know that `c=d=C=D`, the overlap condition `c >= D` and `d <= C` must be true.