# Find Date and Time clashes

Tags: algorithm

I'm having a hard time identifying booking clashes in my system. I've developed a booking system that integrates with our core system. The column data that is stored in my booking system is:

```
ResourceID, StartDate, EndDate, StartTime, EndTime
```

I need to ensure that when another user tries to book a resource, the resource is available. This question has been asked by many, but its usually with one date and start and end time or intersecting between a start date and enddate .

If I wanted to solely check on intersecting dates or time, the formula to use would be

```
a=existing_booking
b=new_booking

overlap = a.start < b.end && b.start < a.end;
```

I then found a really good and interesting post regarding overlapping resources containing both start time and end time [Code Logic to prevent clash between two reservations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25196411/code-logic-to-prevent-clash-between-two-reservations) but they deal with a reoccurring event over multiple days.

I need to ensure if a resource is booked between 8:50 to 22:00 from the 07-23-2016 to 07-29-2016 ; that someone trying to book on the 07-25-2016 to 07-25-2016 at 08:00 to 08:30 can't book it as it is booked out. After numerous searches I can't seem to find the formula for this, can anyone help post the algorithm or send me a link to an existing answer as its driving me nuts.

Comment: Why would a booking from 8:00 to 8:30 conflict with a booking from 8:50 to 22:00?

Comment: if someone books out a minibus for a trip at 8:50 on the 07-23-2016 and returns it back at 22:00 on the 07-29-2016 then if someone tries to book it on 07-25-2016 at 8:00 to 8:30 the minibus would not be available.

Comment: OK, so these aren't complicate recurrences, they are just simple intervals. In that case can't you just combine the date and time to create a datetime and use the normal overlap comparison?  It would be unusual to store a datetime as two separate values in most programming languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you try the below logic?

```
01  if (new.StartDate > existing.EndDate OR new.EndDate < existing.StartDate) {
02      resource is available for booking
03  } else if (new.EndDate = existing.StartDate AND new.StartDate <= existing.StartDate) {
04      if (new.EndTime =< existing.StartTime OR new.StartTime >= existing.EndTime) {
05          resource is available for booking
06      } else {
07          resource is NOT available for booking
08      }
09  } else if (new.StartDate = existing.EndDate) {
10      if (new.StartTime >= existing.EndTime) {
11          resource is available for booking
12      } else {
13          resource is NOT available for booking
14      }
15  } else {
16      resource is NOT available for booking
17  }
```

lets check on a case to case basis;
pass - resource is available
fail - resource is NOT available

An existing booking is in place

```
ResourceID  | StartDate     | EndDate       | StartTime | EndTime
ID1234      | 07-23-2016    | 07-29-2016    | 08:50     | 22:00
```

Case 1

```
ResourceID  | StartDate     | EndDate       | StartTime | EndTime
ID1234      | 07-25-2016    | 07-25-2016    | 08:00     | 08:30
```

result - this case would fail; @line 16 in the code above

Case 2

```
ResourceID  | StartDate     | EndDate       | StartTime | EndTime
ID1234      | 07-23-2016    | 07-23-2016    | 08:00     | 08:30
```

result - this case would pass; @line 05 in the code above

Case 3

```
ResourceID  | StartDate     | EndDate       | StartTime | EndTime
ID1234      | 07-29-2016    | 07-29-2016    | 22:01     | 22:30
```

result - this case would pass; @line 11 in the code above

Case 4

```
ResourceID  | StartDate     | EndDate       | StartTime | EndTime
ID1234      | 07-23-2016    | 07-23-2016    | 09:00     | 11:30
```

result - this case would fail; @line 07 in the code above

Please do check and let me know if for any case the above logic would be giving an in correct answer.

Comment: Thank you, I think the logic works fine from the basic tests I have done. I will do a couple of more tests in the morning and mark as correct answer.

Comment: Sure. However you can also consider the suggestion given by @IanMercer. Unless your underlying design itself has date and time as different fields.